# Elastic server running out of space on VirtualBox?

Tags: elasticsearch, virtualbox

I'm running the frontend part of a project which uses an Elastic search server on a VirtualBox instance.
This is the error I'm getting:
`[FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];]`.

Checking if there is enough disk space with `df -h` showed the following output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            982M     0  982M   0% /dev
tmpfs           201M  6,3M  194M   4% /run
/dev/sda1        23G   17G  5,3G  76% /
tmpfs          1001M  1,4M  999M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5,0M  4,0K  5,0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs          1001M     0 1001M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
D_DRIVE         379G  285G   95G  76% /media/sf_D_DRIVE
tmpfs           201M  8,0K  201M   1% /run/user/108
tmpfs           201M   36K  201M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Do I still need to add space to the VirtualBox instance? Trying to unlock indices with `curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'` returned `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9200: Connection refused`. I'm not sure though if I specified the correct location and port.

How do I get the Elastic server to run?

Comment: It seems that your configuration is wrong and the service is not working properly.

Comment: Please give us more information in which scenario the error message occurres. This error mostly occurres when you try to ingest data to an index that is set to read-only or when the disk watermark is reached. How much storage do your indices take at the moment? Depending on the elasticsearch watermark you may have NOT enough free disk space although df -h gives you numbers that are under 100%

Comment: By default the low watermark is at 85% and the high one is at 90%. (See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html for reference)

Comment: Also note that Elasticsearch will prevent ingesting data that WILL exceed the watermark after storing them. So for example if you have 70% disk space left but your bulk ingestion will lead to 86% disk space, elasticsearch will block these index requests preventively.